# Can I install SQL Server 2012 Express edition on a same machine with 2012 SQL Server Standard version

Tags: sql-server-2012, windows-server, downgrade

As I would like to say that we are going to downgrade the `SQL Server Standard 2012 SP1 edition` with `SQL Server Express 2012 SP4` in one Production Server.

For the time being I want to keep the SQL Server Standard 2012 SP1 in that server and I want to install the SQL Server Express 2012 SP4. Until unless the SQL Server Express 2012 SP4 will be not come to production. Till time I want to keep the SQL Server 2012 Standard SP1.

> My Question is that at the same time can I install the SQL Server
>   Express 2012 SP4 along with the SQL Server Standard 2012 SP1 in the
>   same Server.

**Note :** Suppose that as the Running SQL Server 2012 Standard SP1 instance name is **`ABC`**. Can I install the same instance name (**`ABC`**) of SQL Server 2012 Express SP4 or it will be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My Question is that at the same time can I install the SQL Server Express 2012 SP1 along with the SQL Server Standard 2012 SP1 in the same Server.

Yes installing multiple instances of SQL Server on same machine is fully supported. The only thing is please try to upgrade the instances to SP4 ASAP. SQL Server 2012 Sp1 is not supported.

> Suppose that as the Running SQL Server 2012 Standard SP1 instance name is ABC. Can I install the same instance name (ABC) of SQL Server 2012 Express SP1 or it will be different.

No you cannot, two instances cannot have same instance name, you can use ABC_new this may help in making least change in connection string, if required.

Comment: >>> you can use ABC_new and later change it back to ABC when you remove standard instance<<< You cannot change instance name later. At least, in documented manner. May be you meant "pc rename", but pc name remains the same all the time, and all that OP wants is to change the name of named SQL Server instance

Comment: Yep correct, the instance name cannot be changed unless you uninstall and reinstall, answer updated.

Comment: @Shanky,Nice to see your response , As I have one doubt here what about the port 1433. Suppose that ABC instance of first Server is using the port 1433 , if i will installed second instance with ABC_new in same server. As my knowledge the new instance ABC_new will also use port 1433 or else.

Comment: The second instance would not use port 1433 if first instance is using it, you may set it to use other port or let is use dynamic ports. I *mostly* suggest to keep static port. Please read [How to configure SQL Server to listen on a specific port](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/823938/how-to-configure-sql-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-port)

Comment: @Shanky, I have installed SQL Server express 2012 in the same server where it is SQL Server 2012 Standard. The SQL Server 2012 Standard is running with static port 1433. And express is running with dynamic port. IS it possible to access SQL Server 2012 standard databases with SQL Server 2012 express instance. Because due to production server , do not want to loss of any transaction in database.

Comment: Yes it is possible, go ahead by all means

Comment: @Shanky, As per given instruction you as well as Mr. sepupic, finally I am able to accomplished my downgraded task. Even the remote end user is able to connect with SQL Server Express 2012 instance. Finally i am going to accept answer.

Comment: @Shanky, As I have accepted your answer due to continuously chat with respect to concern query. Even though the Mr. sepupic has given the first answer to this question and point out the (You cannot have two named instances of SQL Server with the same name on the same pc.).

Answer (score 2):

> Suppose that as the Running SQL Server 2012 Standard SP1 instance name
>   is ABC. Can I install the same instance name (ABC) of SQL Server 2012
>   Express SP1 or it will be different.

You cannot have two named instances of SQL Server **with the same name** on the same pc.

So your options are

- first uninstall your first instance and then install the second and
  use the old name for newly installed second instance
- give the second instance different name, but you can then alias it
  with the first server's name once you uninstalled the first server

Here you can find information about [aliases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/create-or-delete-a-server-alias-for-use-by-a-client?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Nice to see your response , As I have one doubt here what about the port 1433. Suppose that ABC instance of first Server is using the port 1433 , if i will installed second instance with ABC_new in same server. As my knowledge the new instance ABC_new will also use port 1433 or else.

Comment: No, your think is not correct. Port 1433 is reserved for DEFAULT instance, that is why you can connect to default instance using only IP or PC name. You instead have a named instance, so by default is uses dynamic port that you can see in error log or in Configuration Manager

Comment: You could configured your instance to use 1433, but this way you exclude the possibility of having the default instance on the same pc. Anyway, if you will insist and configure the second instance to use the same port as the first instance, only ONE instance will start, the other will give you an error on startup and will not start.

Comment: ,ok, one more thing during the installation of SQL Server Express 2012 . Is it required to stop the SQL Server 2012 Standard Server. Because It's Live Server some of the remote (offshore) user is accessing that Server. I want to install SQL Server 2012 Express along with running of SQL Server 2012 Standard. Can I proceed the installation?

Comment: No, you do not need to stop other instances running on the machine where you want to install SQL server, as a added safety measure install the SQL Server when load is relatively very less.